# How to get all product in a father_id in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
brand(id, parent_id, name)
      1 |     0    | Apple
      2 |     0    | Samsung
      3 |     1    | Iphone 3S
      4 |     1    | Iphone 4S
product(id, name)
        1 | OS
        2 | Andriod
product_brand(product_id, brand_id)
                  1     |    3
                  1     |    4
```

And mysql:
How to get `product name` when `brand name = Apple`

```
SELECT * FROM product_brand
LEFT JOIN brand ON brand.id = product_brand.brand_id
WHERE brand.id = 1 // Apple
```

Ex: if get Apple(id=1) is result => OS, If get Samsung(id=2) is result => Andriod

Comment: I don't see a real question in there; what's your expected result? Also, your `product_brand` table is missing the rows for brand 1 & 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  p.name
FORM product p
LEFT JOIN product_brand pb ON p.id = pb.product_id
LEFT JOIN brand b ON pb.brand_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN brand b1 ON b.id = b1.parent_id
WHERE b1.name = 'Apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT
  childbrand,name AS child_brand_name
  product.name AS product_name
FROM brand AS childbrand
INNER JOIN brand AS parentbrand ON parentbrand.id=childbrand.parent_id
INNER JOIN product_brand ON product_brand.brand_id=childbrand.id
INNER JOIN product ON product_brand.product_id=product.id
WHERE parentbrand.name='Apple';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the product name specifically of Apple and Samsung which is not stored at product_brand (see that from the sample data). You could fix the query as below:

```
 SELECT *,
    CASE b.name WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'iOS'
    WHEN 'Samsung' THEN 'Android' ELSE '-' END  
   FROM
    brand b
```

Edited 2:
If you want to get all the product name based on the parent_id. Could try the below:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE b.name WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'iOS'
    WHEN 'Samsung' THEN 'Android' ELSE '-' END as type_of_os
FROM
    brand b 
WHERE parent_id=0
UNION
SELECT
    b.*,
    CASE b2.name WHEN 'Apple' THEN 'iOS'
    WHEN 'Samsung' THEN 'Android' ELSE '-' END as type_of_os
FROM
    brand b
INNER JOIN
    brand b2 ON b.parent_id = b2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f573/18